# Putting Key-Value Pairs in an Object - Why does it Order the entries by #?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Below is my code.  I'm putting a number and it's double as key-value pairs into an object.  I'm curious as to why it is ordering the result by #.  As in why does the '13': 26 entry come before '21': 42, when 13 comes after 21 in the array?  Thanks for any insight.

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,8,7,21,13];
var object = {};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
object[array[i]] = double(array[i]);
}

function double(a){
return a*2;
}

console.log(object);
```

Here is what I get in my console:

```
{ '1': 2,
'2': 4,
'3': 6,
'4': 8,
'5': 10,
'7': 14,
'8': 16,
'13': 26,
'21': 42 }
```

Comment: [__Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects are generally not ordered and you shouldn't rely on the properties to be in order. <strike>You can try this snippet to get the result in order:</strike>

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,8,7,21,13];
var object = {};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
object[array[i]] = double(array[i]);
}

function double(a){
return a*2;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```

---

**EDIT**

The above snippet will not guarantee the order because:

> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered
>   collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function.

So the order you're getting in your code will depend on how your browser interprets it (since there is no exact rule defined it might sort by keys in ascending order).

A method to preserve this order is to use arrays (which are ordered). This is an example using **array of objects**:

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,8,7,21,13];
var object = []; // changed this to an array

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var newObject = {};
  
  // in order to insert keys as variables
  newObject[array[i]] = double(array[i]);
  object.push(newObject);
}

function double(a){
return a*2;
}

console.log(object);
```

**Note:** I've created an object first before pushing it to the array. This is necessary if you want your key values to be set from some variable.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  Your snippet resulted in the same result as mine.  I'm asking why my coding IS ordering the results.

Comment: @AugustusBrennan I've updated my answer, hope it makes more sense now. P. S. JavaScript can be so confusing (but fun) sometimes.